# Viewable (but 404'ed) Edit link on candidate pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, election

Viewing another candidates introduction will show an edit link (at least for me). [Example page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/38838/revisions). Clicking on this link will yield a [404 error](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/38838/edit/534f0be5-e3c1-4379-aac0-9f63ce9c4c4c). Brought this up on the [Programmers.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/427907#427907).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit link is now removed from that page.  Thanks for the report.